# How to Call a static page in WordPress

Tags: customization

Hi I created a template within my theme files, just for displaying a map in a lightbox. I need to call this template page from a normal wordpress post, how can I do it?

Say in my theme files I have a file called map-template.php
From within my post I would like to call that map-template.php file and also pass the ID of the current post as a parameter.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as you have a standard [page template header](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates) in your `map-template.php`, you can use the [Custom Post Template plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-template/) (which essentially allows you use templates on posts in the same way you do with pages).

**Update**: Perhaps you might be better off using [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).

For example;

```
This is my post content in the editor. And here is a map;

[my-map]
```

And in `functions.php`;

```
function __my_map_shortcode()
{
     // output map
}
add_shortcode( 'my-map', '__my_map_shortcode' );
```

Comment: But I don't want to associate this template with any post or page.

Comment: Having re-read your question, I think you might be better off using shortcode. See my revised answer.

Comment: Yep; I would go the shortcode route.